remove SOAP envelope from xml
I have below input XML with SOAP envelope and need to remove soap envelope in output xml.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <Messages xmlns="http://web.ui.com">
        <result failed="0" scheduled="0" sent="1">
            <Details limit="4" rem="2" type="ys"/>
        </result>
    </Messages>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

I have used below XSLT code but it's not giving the expected output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns="http://web.ui.com"
            version="1.0">
       <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="/SOAP-ENV:Envelope">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SOAP-ENV:Body/*"/>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="SOAP-ENV:Body">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>

Expected output
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Messages xmlns="http://web.ui.com">
        <result failed="0" scheduled="0" sent="1">
            <Details limit="4" rem="2" type="ys"/>
        </result>
       </Messages>

so the code should work irrespective of the fields and nodes inside Messages node.

Your attempt, although over-complicated, does return the expected result - albeit with some redundant namespace declarations, which should NOT pose a problem for the target application.

In XSLT 2.0 you can do simply:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/SOAP-ENV:Envelope">
    <xsl:copy-of select="SOAP-ENV:Body/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Hi Michael, unfortunately my application is supporting only 1.0 version.

Then don't tag your question as xslt-2.0.

An XSLT 1.0 solution that drops the unused namespaces:
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"  />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/*" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
            
</xsl:stylesheet>

